# How to find entries with no category

Tags: categories, elementcriteriamodel

I have a field `categories` in a channel `news`, and I want to find all the entries in `news` that don't have a category set. I know I could loop over the entries and find them that way, but I'm hoping to do it with a query. I tried

```
{% set uncategorized = craft.entries.section('news').categories(':empty:') %}
```

But it returned none.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this in a single query using the search parameter:

```twig
{% set uncategorized = craft.entries.section('news').search('-categories:*') %}
```

More on [searching here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching).

Comment: Cool, nice answer.

Comment: This is returning all of my entries, including the one with a category in news.categories

Comment: strange, it works for me. are you on v2.1 and is your field handle "categories"?

Comment: very latest 2.1.2561 and field handle categories. The category group is newsCategory

Comment: can you rebuild the search indexes (on the settings page) and then try again?

Comment: That fixed it! And also the parallel problem I was having with untagged entries. Thank you so much!

Comment: great, i've reported a bug to P&T which should address this issue in future

Comment: fixed in this update http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2563

Answer (score 4):

If you're wanting to avoid a loop, I think the best solution here would be to find the entries which *do* have a category set and work backwards using the [`|without()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#without) filter. I can't see this being possible in only one query.

```
{# First, get your categories #}
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('optionalGroup').ids() %}

{# Find all news entries which have a category set #}
{% set newsWithCategories = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo({targetElement: categories}).ids() %}

{# Now find news without categories #}
{% set newsWithoutCategories = craft.entries.section('news').ids()|without(newsWithCategories) %}

{# Finally retrieve the EntryModels #}
{% set newsEntries = craft.entries.section('news').id(newsWithoutCategories).find() %}
```

As you can see, there are quite a few calls to the DB being made here. This little algorithm would probably be more efficient with a loop.

```
{% set newsEntries = [] %}
{% for news in craft.entries.section('news').find() %}
    {% if news.categories is empty %}
        {% set newsEntries = newsEntries|merge([news]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That loop is looking better and better.